# Wrong network icon used on chat notifications when in multiple channels?

Tags: bug, chat, ping

When you're in multiple channels associated with multiple different networks, the channel notifications popup seems to just choose one of those networks and always use the icon for that network.

For example, I am in channels associated with Information Security, Arqade, Game Development, Anime & Manga, eBooks, and Super User.

However, when I receive a chat notification, these notifications appear with the Information Security logo regardless of where the notification occurred:

[image]

What I would expect to see, is the logo of the site that the channel the notification occurred in was sent to, so in the above instance, Arqade.

Can this get fixed?

Comment: It seems to be by-design, but I still want this fixed

Comment: It's not a very good design, if it is by design...

Comment: @JanDvorak How can that be by-design? I mean, that icon is just *plain wrong* in almost every way possible.

Comment: @FEichinger it tells you which chat generated the notification

Comment: @JanDvorak that doesn't mean it's by design, each network can have multiple chat rooms and in those instances using the icon for that network for all of them would be correct.

Comment: It happens only to ping trolls. :D

Comment: @FEichinger Having complained about this before, I know it is bydesign in the sense that it wasn't really worth fixing. The icon of course is just whichever tab is responsible for getting notifications at the time.